# CSS styling links isn't working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

This is my CSS style sheet:

```
a:link {color:green;}
a:visited {color:yellow;}
a:hover {color:black;} 
a:active {color:blue;}
div.ex
{
font-family:Impact;
letter-spacing:1px;
font-size:60px;
position:relative;left:200px;top:15px;
color:#DEDEDE;
text-shadow: -1px 0 red, 0  1px red, 0 1px  red, 0 -1px red;
}
body
{
background:url("hello.gif");

background-size:100% 12%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.h
{
font-family:"Comic Sans MS";
letter-spacing:2px;
font-size:40px;
position:fixed;left:570px;top:12px;
color:#E6001A;
text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0  2px black, 0 2px  black, 0 -2px black;
}
.border
{
border-style:ridge;
border-color:white;
}
```

This is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ex2.css">
</head>
<body>
</head>
<div class="ex"><b>Zrack</b></div>
<hr class="border">
<a href="file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Site/main.html">HOME</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I am linking it to something on my own computer. It does visit the page but the color remains default.Please point out what I am doing wrong. I have been trying to figure this out for 2 hours.

Comment: The color of *what* remains default?  Are you clicking on the link to the file:// URL, navigating back, and expecting to see that the link color changed because of the a:visited specification?  Or what?  Don't make us guess - please tell us *what* element you're wondering about, what color it *is*, what color you *expect* it to be, and *why* you expecit it to be that color.  You'll probably get better answers faster.

Comment: a:link {color:green;}
a:visited {color:yellow;}
a:hover {color:black;} 
a:active {color:blue;}

Comment: I am asking about the above part. The href remains default. The link isn't green nor when I hover over it, it changes into black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `href` and not with the CSS.

Change...

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Site/main.html">HOME</a>
```

to

```
<a href="main.html">HOME</a>
```

and it will work. (You should be using a webserver and linking to files like the above and not as a file link.)

Also, there is an error in your HTML. You have two closing `head` tags and one of them is closing after the `body` tag is opened...

```
</head>
<body>
</head>
```

All the best.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. :) and ty for pointing out the error. I am just a beginner

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark this answer as accepted by selecting the tick mark if you are happy with the answer.